# Virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied error when running Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've installed Virtualenvwrapper, and it seems to be running fine, but anytime I activate an env or run workon venv I get the following:

```
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied: 
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied:
```

This is what my .bash_profile looks like

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Here are my packages

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
distlib           0.3.4
filelock          3.7.0
pbr               5.9.0
pip               22.1.1
platformdirs      2.5.2
setuptools        49.2.1
six               1.15.0
stevedore         3.5.0
virtualenv        20.14.1
virtualenv-clone  0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4
wheel             0.36.2
```

I am using Python3.8.9

It looks like my environment activated, but I'm not a fan of seeing an error message I don't understand.

Comment: have you try `sudo` yet?

Comment: I have tried installing with sudo. It just informs me that the packages are already installed.

Answer (score 8):

I used `vi ~/.zshrc` to open my `.zshrc` file. Then I changed it to the following:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /Users/username/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Replacing username with my actual user name.

I ran:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

and it now all works. I think this is because for mac terminal I needed to edit my `.zshrc` file. I also downloaded the `virtualenvwrapper` package with `pipx` initially.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used `homebrew` to install `python3` in my **Apple M2**. Where the script for `virtualenwrapper` is located at: `/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

Additionally, I don't have `python` linked, but `python3` instead. As `virtualenvwrapper` will look for the python executable using `command which python` I was getting the error:

```
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied:
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Adding then `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` whith the `python3` path fixed my issue. This is how my profile looks like:

```bash
# Virtualenvwrapper
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: this also solves the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS because of it is  `python3` not `python` and explains better than the highest-upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the answers above.
**Solution**: Add the following line `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` to the `.zshrc` config file. Running `source ~/.zshrc` to reload the file and apply the changes run successfully without the prior error:

```
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied:
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Oddly enough, that line of code was not included in the `virtualenvwrapper` [installation docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#:%7E:text=export%20WORKON_HOME%3D%24HOME/.virtualenvs%0Aexport%20PROJECT_HOME%3D%24HOME/Devel%0Asource%20/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh).

**Other information:**

- **NB**: If you alternate between different Python versions on your machine (ie. `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`), you may encounter the following error when launching the terminal with a Python version different from the one used to install  `virtualenvwrapper`:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

- My current `virtualenvwrapper` config in my `.zshrc` file:

```
# virtualenvwrapper configuration
#
## Set the following:
### - path for installing py interpreter
### - where the virtual envs should live
### - path for development project dirs
### - path for virtualenv installation
### - path of the package's installed script
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=$HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv

source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**Context:**
OS: Ubuntu Focal LTS (20.04.6)
Interpreter: `Python 3.8.10`